# Is Tiagra 10 speed chain different to regular 10 speed chain?

Tags: shimano, chain, tiagra

Shimano Tiagra 10 speed systems are oddball - they have the cable pull of an 11 speed on 10 cogs in a cassette.  Thus derailleurs and shifters and cassette are not interoperable with regular 10 speed components.

Is a tiagra CN-4601 chain interchangeable with generic 10 speed chain like CN-HG54.

---

I measured some new authentic Tiagra 4601 chain and got 5.95mm on the widest point, which was outside of the rivets.

Measuring some well-used SRAM X10 chain I got 6.2mm, and some knockoff new shimano-faux chain was 6.25mm.

Some googling suggests that 11 speed chain ranges from 5.4mm to 5.7mm

Is Tiagra 10 speed chain interchangeable with other 10 speed, or is it really just a thicker 11 speed chain ?

Comment: @MaplePanda almost - its the same subject approached from the other side, but the answers are excellent

Comment: I hope the other question‘s answers were able to give you the information you need though. End of the day, you have the power to reopen if you want ;)

Comment: @MaplePanda heh yeah a search didn't suggest that; by adding this question there's more chance it will find it in the future.  The system works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'new 10' Shimano groups take any 10-speed Shimano road double (aka directional) chain per the charts, or in practice any 10-speed chain.